# Can I use Ubuntu installed on external HDD on Macbook Air?

Tags: mac, external-hdd, macbook-air

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on external USB hard drive.

Can I use that same installation (on same USB HDD) on Macbook Air? Can you give me some advices how to boot it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am familiar with a windows enviroment, when i'm using a a windows computer, I enter the BIOS settings and change the boot sequence so it checks if it can boot from a USB device before it goes to the hard drive.  As i have looked online, apparently, there is no BIOS on a Mac, but there is a program called EFI apparently, where you can change the boot order from the hard drive(or solid state drive) being first to making your external hard drive first.
[This link is about the boot order changing program, EFI.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)

[This link is somewhat about how to use it.](https://superuser.com/questions/373151/wheres-the-bios-on-an-intel-mac)

EDIT: There also was a thing on the apple website that said if you press "c" during start up, it will boot from a bootable CD, DVD, or USB drive.  If this works, it might be easier.  [MORE INFO](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533)

Sorry if this was not enough information for you, hopefully it is, but i could not test it out, as i do not have a mac.

Comment: For booting right now I use Grub4Dos, because I have no boot manager on external HDD. What kind of boot manager do I need on Mac?

Comment: There also was a thing on the apple website that said if you press "c" during start up, it will boot from a bootable CD, DVD, or USB drive. If this works, it might be easier. - not related to what you just said, but it might work better

Comment: Yeah, you can configure it to boot from your external hardrive. You just need to change boot sequence.

Comment: ok, but on windows, i need to have vmlinuz and several more files for proper boot of linux on external hdd. what about mac?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just configure your BIOS to boot from your external drive.